# How to merge duplicate rows in Excel based on column A and keep data

Tags: excel, merge, pivot-table, rows

I have a .csv with a table that looks like this:

[image]

and I would like to merge the values in the rows that are duplicate
based on column A.
The end result to be like this:

[image]

I would appreciate a bit of help please as I've tried with PivotTable in Excel  but I must be doing something wrong
as it messes up the data.

Answer (score 0):

How important is column B, because that's the only gotcha I see.  Otherwise, this setup in a pivot table should give you the totals you seek.

[image]

For column B, you can always use a vlookup out to the side, but since you have multiple, it should pull the first value -- somewhat arbitrary:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$10,2,FALSE)
```